# Simple A star algorithm Tower Defense Path Trapped

Tags: java, a-star

So first of all I'm in a 100 level CS college class that uses Java. Our assignment is to make a tower defense game and I am having trouble with the pathing. I found from searching that A* seems to be the best for this. Though my pathing get's stuck when I put a U around the path. I'll show some beginner psuedo code since I haven't taken a data structures class yet and my code looks pretty messy(working on that).

Assume that I will not be using diagonals.

```
while(Castle not reached){
    new OpenList
    if(up, down, left, right == passable && isn't previous node){
         //Adds in alternating order to create a more diagonal like path
         Openlist.add(passable nodes)
    }
    BestPath.add(FindLeasDistancetoEnd(OpenList));
    CheckCastleReached(BestPath[Last Index]);
{

private node FindLeastDistancetoEnd(node n){
    return first node with Calculated smallest (X + Y to EndPoint)
}
```

I've stripped A* down(too much, my problem most likely). So I'm adding parents to my nodes and calculating the correct parent though I don't believe this will solve my problem. Here's a visual of my issue.

X = impassable(Towers)

O = OpenList

b = ClosedList(BestPath)

C = Castle(EndPoint)

S = Start

```
OOOOXX
SbbbBX   C
OOOOXX
```

Now the capitol B is where my issue is. When the towers are placed in that configuration and my Nav Path is recalculated it gets stuck. Nothing is put into the OpenList since the previous node is ignored and the rest are impassable.

Writing it out now I suppose I could make B impassable and backtrack... Lol. Though I'm starting to do a lot of what my professor calls "hacking the code" where I keep adding patches to fix issues, because I don't want to erase my "baby" and start over. Although I am open to redoing it, looking at how messy and unorganized some of my code is bothers me, can't wait to take data structures.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, data structures would help you a lot on this sort of problem. I'll try to explain how A* works and give some better Pseudocode afterwards.

A* is a Best-First search algorithm. This means that it's supposed to guess which options are best, and try to explore those first. This requires you to keep track of a list of options, typically called the "Front" (as in front-line). It doesn't keep track of a path found so far, like in your current algorithm. The algorithm works in two phases...

**Phase 1**

Basically, you start from the starting position `S`, and all the neighbouring positions (north, west, south and east) will be in the Front. The algorithm then finds the most promising of the options in the Front (let's call it `P`), and expands on that. The position `P` is removed from the Front, but all of its neighbours are added in stead. Well, not all of its neighbours; only the neighbours that are actual options to go. We can't go walking into a tower, and we wouldn't want to go back to a place we've seen before. From the new Front, the most promising option is chosen, and so on. When the most promising option is the goal `C`, the algorithm stops and enters phase 2.

Normally, the most promising option would be the one that is closest to the goal, as the crow flies (ignoring obstacles). So normally, it would always explore the one that is closest to the goal first. This causes the algorithm to walk towards the goal in a sort-of straight line. However, if that line is blocked by some obstacle, the positions of the obstacle should *not* be added to the Front. They are not viable options. So in the next round then, some other position in the Front would be selected as the best option, and the search continues from there. That is how it gets out of dead ends like the one in your example. Take a look at this illustration to get what I mean: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Astar_progress_animation.gif The Front is the hollow blue dots, and they mark dots where they've already been in a shade from red to green, and impassable places with thick blue dots.

In phase 2, we will need some extra information to help us find the shortest path back when we found the goal. For this, we store in every position the position we came from. If the algorithm works, the position we came from necessarily is closer to `S` than any other neighbour. Take a look at the pseudocode below if you don't get what I mean.

**Phase 2**

When the castle `C` is found, the next step is to find your way back to the start, gathering what was the best path. In phase 1, we stored the position we came from in every position that we explored. We know that this position must always be closer to `S` (not ignoring obstacles). The task in phase 2 is thus very simple: Follow the way back to the position we came from, every time, and keep track of these positions in a list. At the end, you'll have a list that forms the shortest path from `C` to `S`. Then you simply need to reverse this list and you have your answer.

I'll give some pseudocode to explain it. There are plenty of real code examples (in Java too) on the internet. This pseudocode assumes you use a 2D array to represent the grid. An alternative would be to have Node objects, which is simpler to understand in Pseudocode but harder to program and I suspect you'd use a 2D array anyway.

```
//Phase 1
origins = new array[gridLength][gridWidth]; //Keeps track of 'where we came from'.
front = new Set(); //Empty set. You could use an array for this.
front.add(all neighbours of S);
while(true) { //This keeps on looping forever, unless it hits the "break" statement below.
    best = findBestOption(front);
    front.remove(best);
    for(neighbour in (best's neighbours)) {
        if(neighbour is not a tower and origins[neighbour x][neighbour y] == null) { //Not a tower, and not a position that we explored before.
            front.add(neighbour);
            origins[neighbour x][neighbour y] = best;
        }
    }
    if(best == S) {
        break; //Stops the loop. Ends phase 1.
    }
}

//Phase 2
bestPath = new List(); //You should probably use Java's ArrayList class for this if you're allowed to do that. Otherwise select an array size that you know is large enough.
currentPosition = C; //Start at the endpoint.
bestPath.add(C);
while(currentPosition != S) { //Until we're back at the start.
    currentPosition = origins[currentPosition.x][currentPosition.y];
    bestPath.add(currentPosition);
}
bestPath.reverse();
```

And for the `findBestOption` method in that pseudocode:

```
findBestOption(front) {
    bestPosition = null;
    distanceOfBestPosition = Float.MAX_VALUE; //Some very high number to start with.
    for(position in front) {
        distance = Math.sqrt(position.x * position.x - C.x * C.x + position.y * position.y - C.y * C.y); //Euclidean distance (Pythagoras Theorem). This does the diagonal thing for you.
        if(distance < distanceOfBestPosition) {
            distanceOfBestPosition = distance;
            bestPosition = position;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps. Feel free to ask on!

Comment: Thanks for all the info. I started over and implemented with the help of your psuedo code and explanation. Couple of Notes. First your Euclidean Distance just has X values in the psuedo code. I used: 'Math.sqrt(Math.pow(X - EndPoint.x(), 2) + Math.pow(Y - EndPoint.y(),2));' Second I don't believe your method includes assigning new parents or elimination origins in your example I suppose. Unless I missed a step. In my implementation I get a lot of extra paths into closed of U's then it goes back out and finds the correct path. I'm working on assigning new parents.

Comment: Good answer, but it is preferable to be able to assign new parents, as "shorter" paths to closed nodes can be found after the initial discovery -- for example, a shorter backtrack around an obstacle. Closed nodes and their back paths remain relevant since they may be used as parents (back paths) of open nodes still under exploration.

Comment: The Euclidean distance function was indeed wrong. Don't know what I was thinking. Updated it. `Math.pow()` works, but multiplying is faster. It seems that parents (`origins`) can indeed change, according to Wikipedia. My mistake. I hope you figured it out by now.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the A* algorithm properly. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2A_search_algorithm

On every iteration, you need to:

1. sort the *open nodes* into heuristic order,
2. pick the best;
3. -- check if you have reached the goal, and potentially terminate if so;
4. mark it as 'closed' now, since it will be fully explored from.
5. explore all neighbors from it (by adding to the *open nodes* map/ or list, if not already *closed*).

Based on the ASCII diagram you posted, it's not absolutely clear that the height of the board is more than 3 & that there actually is a path around -- but let's assume there is.

The proper A* algorithm doesn't "get stuck" -- when the *open list* is empty, no path exists & it terminates returning a no path `null`.

I suspect you may not be closing the open nodes (this should be done as you start processing them), or may not be processing all open nodes on every iteration.

Use a `Map<GridPosition, AStarNode>` will help performance in checking for all those neighboring positions, whether they are in the open or closed sets/lists.

Comment: Appreciate the response. "Implement the A* algorithm properly." Yeah I found I can't take shortcuts with algorithms.

Comment: Edited my post to reflect the correct A* algorithm, thinking on my code & realized I had mislead you as to which nodes (just the best one) to explore each iteration. Yes, you do need to implement algorithms correctly -- otherwise they do something else. Hope this helps.  @Spero